# How to add $id = $_GET['student_id']; and show all same id

Tags: php, mysql

Im so very paranoid for my code because this is our thesis.
I want to show all row with the same id using $_GET['student_id'] but datatables error this is my code.

```
<?php
include('db.php');
include('function.php');
$query = '';
$output = array();
$id = $_GET['student_id'];
$query = 'SELECT * FROM personal WHERE student_id LIKE "%'.$_GET["student_id"].'%" ';
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$data = array();
$filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $image = '';
    if($row["image"] != '')
    {
        $image = '<img src="upload/'.$row["image"].'" class="img-thumbnail" width="50" height="35" />';
    }
    else
    {
        $image = '';
    }
    $sub_array = array();
    $sub_array[] = $row["student_id"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["firstname"]." ".$row['middlename']." ".$row['lastname'];
    $sub_array[] = '<a href="edit.php?student_id='.$row["student_id"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs update">Personal Info</a>'." ".
    '<button type="button" id="'.$row["student_id"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs update">Grades</button>'." ".
    '<button type="button" id="'.$row["student_id"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs update">Payment</button>';
    $sub_array[] = '<a href="view.php?student_id='.$row["student_id"].'" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs update">View</a>';
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$row["student_id"].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete">Delete</button>';
    $data[] = $sub_array;
}
$output = array(
    "draw"              =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
    "recordsTotal"      =>  $filtered_rows,
    "recordsFiltered"   =>  get_total_all_records(),
    "data"              =>  $data
);
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you shouldn't use a `LIKE %xy%` when searching for an id. Is there a specific reason why you do that instead of a simple `=`?

Comment: what do you have in $_GET['student_id']`? You should btw. check if there is a valid value in there before you continue. Also use prepared statements, because your code is unsecure.

Comment: so please how will I do ? 
I want to show all row with the same id

Comment: just `'....WHERE student_id='.$_GET["student_id"].';'`. BUT look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and transition to those!

Comment: so u write $id = $_GET['student_id'] but u still use the $_GET in your statement and not $id?

Comment: Please show us the datatable code you use for this, since that's where3 your error is. Your data field is being looped in Javascript? And you are defining 5 columns in the DT code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `student_id` is numeric:

```
$id = intval($_GET['student_id']);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM personal WHERE student_id = '.$id;
```

Would be safe enough.

Also, this looks like an AJAX call. Let's see your Javascript calling and HTML to see if Datatable is being called right from your AJAX call

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the $_GET['student_id'] with mysqli_real_escape_string or any other procedure... for security or even better use PDO for make queries.